# Possible to use shell script that does loopback to localhost when receiving a packet?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcp, loopback

I want to run a shell script, that sends a packet to localhost (loopback) when it receives a packet from anywhere.

I am using `netcat`.

`nc -lp $port`, and then `echo test | nc localhost $port` works.

But, the same thing inside a shell script, that can execute code when receiving a package, does not.

`nc -lp $port | ./a.sh` and then the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read socket
do
    echo test | nc localhost $port
done
```

It gives the error:

`localhost [127.0.0.1] 2012 (?) : Connection refused`

There is probably a simple explanation to why.

I wonder: is it possible to do what I want to do, somehow?

Why I want to do this: Writing a simple network application that can either talk between nodes, or between accounts on the same node, and I want to use the same code for both (thus interaction between accounts on the same node is via loopback messages instead of just directly. )

Answer (score 1):

OK. I have resolved the question now. It was multiple things that caused the error.

First, `netcat` does not allow multiple connections (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29780420/19923651 for reference. )

I resolved that by using `socat`instead.

Then there were some other issues too, that made me misinterpret my attempts at debugging.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.